# Calculate exhaust with expansion chamber muffler

Tags: automotive-engineering

I have a book with the formulas to calculate the length of engine exhaust pipe, but these formulas don't take into account the muffler.
If I add an expansion chamber, how the calculated length change?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to calculate - show an example with the formula. Just remember the basic : what goes in - comes out...

Comment: It would be very helpful if you gave more detail and what you are hoping to achieve. But guessing you are trying to improve the VE of the engine by using timed reflections, a typical expansion chamber terminates the wave, so it bounces back from that first pipe to muffler junction, with an inverted pressure pulse.

Answer (score 0):

Use typical relations:

$$mass flow= density*area*speed$$

And bear in mind the waves synchronizing. The speed of the wave and its reflections: It reflects when it reaches the muffler (open end). That way you can calculate the length.

$$Time_(exhaust)*speed_(wave)=length$$

How many times do you want the wave to reflect? Bear that in mind too.

Comment: any effects of bends or other changes in diameter?